# Problem whit VBA macros works in Office365

Tags: vba, office365

I faced with problem how macros works after start using Office365. In general macros should fill WORD template tags and bookmarks from txt data file. The problem is somtimes same data from data file doesn't past into template and there isn't any logics. It may be first,last, middele records of table. And more over most of times macros fill all data correctly. In Office2013/2016 all work properly.

Is there any ideas about this?

Macros code

```
   Option Explicit

  Type t_Ar

    Col() As String

  End Type

 

  Dim isAutoOpen As String, _

      WITHOUT_OLE As String, _

      USE_JAR As String, _

      UseUnicode As String, fs, f

     

Private Function GetFullPath(FullName As String) As String

  Dim NameParts, Res As String, i As Integer

  NameParts = Split(FullName, Application.PathSeparator)

  Res = NameParts(0)

  For i = 1 To UBound(NameParts) - 1

    Res = Res + Application.PathSeparator + NameParts(i)

  Next

  GetFullPath = Res

End Function

 

Sub AutoOpen()

  Dim FileNameData As String, FullPathMacros As String, ParsName, Cnt As Integer, _

    AppMacros As Application, DocMacros As Document

 

'Stop

  isAutoOpen = "X"

 

  Set AppMacros = Application

  Set DocMacros = AppMacros.ActiveDocument

 

  'Mac косячит, вместо Path возвращает FullName

'  FullPathMacros = Application.ActiveDocument.Path

  FullPathMacros = GetFullPath(DocMacros.FullName)

 

  ParsName = Split(DocMacros.Name, "_")

  Cnt = UBound(ParsName)

  If Cnt = 3 Then

    If ParsName(0) = "ZWWW" And ParsName(1) = "MACROS" And ParsName(2) = "WORD" Then

     

      If AppMacros.Documents.Count > 1 Then

'        AppMacros.ActiveWindow.Visible = False

      Else

        AppMacros.Visible = False

      End If

     

      ParsName = Split(ParsName(3), ".")

      FileNameData = FullPathMacros + AppMacros.PathSeparator + "ZWWW_DATA_" + ParsName(0) + ".txt"

     

      FillVariables FileNameData, DocMacros

   

      If WITHOUT_OLE = "X" Then

        If AppMacros.Documents.Count > 1 Then

          DocMacros.Close

        Else

          AppMacros.Quit

        End If

      End If

    End If

  End If

  isAutoOpen = ""

End Sub

 

Private Function isFileUnicode(NameFileData As String) As Boolean

  Dim b1 As Byte, b2 As Byte

  isFileUnicode = False

  On Error Resume Next

  Open NameFileData For Random Access Read As #5 Len = 1

   Get #5, 1, b1

   Get #5, 2, b2

  Close #5

  If b1 = 0 Or b2 = 0 Then

    isFileUnicode = True

  End If

End Function

 

Private Sub OpenFileData(FileData As String)

  Dim CodePageTxt As Integer

 

  If UseUnicode <> "X" Then

    Open FileData For Input As #1

  Else

    CodePageTxt = -2

    If UseUnicode = "X" Then

      CodePageTxt = -1

    End If

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(FileData, 1, 0, CodePageTxt)

  End If

End Sub

 

Private Sub CloseFileData()

  If UseUnicode <> "X" Then

    Close #1

  Else

    f.Close

  End If

End Sub

 

Private Function isEndOfFileData() As Boolean

  If UseUnicode <> "X" Then

    isEndOfFileData = EOF(1)

  Else

    isEndOfFileData = f.AtEndOfStream

  End If

End Function

 

Private Function ReadLineData() As String

  Dim Ln As String

  If UseUnicode <> "X" Then

    Line Input #1, Ln

  Else

    Ln = f.ReadLine

  End If

  ReadLineData = Ln

End Function

 

Sub MakeFullDir(FullName As String)

  Dim ArrName, NewDir As String, Cnt As Integer

 

  ArrName = Split(FullName, Application.PathSeparator)

 

  On Error Resume Next

  Err.Clear

 

  Cnt = 0

  Do While Cnt < UBound(ArrName)

    If NewDir = "" Then

      NewDir = ArrName(Cnt)

    Else

      NewDir = NewDir + Application.PathSeparator + ArrName(Cnt)

    End If

    Err.Clear

    ChDir NewDir

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

      Err.Clear

      MkDir NewDir

    End If

    Cnt = Cnt + 1

  Loop

End Sub

 

Public Sub FillVariables(ByVal FileData As String, ByVal DocTempl) ' As Document

  UserFormProgress.UserFormProgressShow FileData, DocTempl

End Sub

 

Public Sub ZWWW_FillVariables(ByVal FileData As String, ByVal DocTempl) ' As Document

  Dim fs, f, _

      Ln As String, r As Range, Ofs As Range, _

      Ar() As t_Ar, i As Long, Cnt As Long, _

      value, CurrRange As Range, _

      RowsCount As Long, _

      MACROSNAME, ErrNumber, VarError, _

      Doc As Document, _

      RangeStart, RangeEnd, RangeSize, _

      NewStart, NewEnd, NewSize, _

      RangeTempl, b As Bookmark, Dupl As Range, Fd As Find, _

      CheckSpel, CheckGram, PasteAdjTblFormat As Boolean

'      FileData As String

'      QTable As QueryTable,

  Dim Param, _

      ProgressStep As Long, _

      Psw As String, _

      ResDialogPrint, _

      TEMP_NAME As String, _

      FILE_NAME As String, _

      FILE_PATH As String, _

      FULL_NAME As String, _

      MACROS_NAME As String, _

      DEBUG_MODE As String, _

      CLOSE_FORM As String, _

      PRINTDIALOG As String, _

      PROTECT_WB As String, _

      StartTime As Date, _

      CurrentTime As Date

 

  StartTime = Time * 100000

  CurrentTime = StartTime

 

  If isFileUnicode(FileData) Then

    UseUnicode = "X"

  Else

    UseUnicode = ""

  End If

 

  RowsCount = 1


  ErrNumber = 0

 

  With Application

    Set Doc = .ActiveDocument

    .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    .ScreenUpdating = False

  End With

  With Options

    CheckSpel = .CheckSpellingAsYouType

    CheckGram = .CheckGrammarAsYouType

    .CheckSpellingAsYouType = False

    .CheckGrammarAsYouType = False

  End With

 

  OpenFileData FileData

 

  Ln = ReadLineData()

 

  Cnt = Ln

 

  Do While Not isEndOfFileData() And Cnt > 0

 

    Cnt = Cnt - 1

   

    Ln = ReadLineData()

   

    Param = Split(Ln, Chr(9))

   

    If UBound(Param) = 1 Then

      Select Case Param(0)

        Case "TEMP_NAME"

          TEMP_NAME = Param(1)

          FULL_NAME = GetFullPath(Application.ActiveDocument.FullName) + Application.PathSeparator + TEMP_NAME

          FULL_NAME = Replace(FULL_NAME, "\", Application.PathSeparator)

          FULL_NAME = Replace(FULL_NAME, "/", Application.PathSeparator)

        Case "FILE_NAME"

          FILE_NAME = Param(1)

        Case "FILE_PATH"

          FILE_PATH = Param(1)

          FILE_PATH = Replace(FILE_PATH, "\", Application.PathSeparator)

          FILE_PATH = Replace(FILE_PATH, "/", Application.PathSeparator)

        Case "WITHOUT_OLE"

          WITHOUT_OLE = Param(1)

          On Error Resume Next

          Open Application.ActiveDocument.Path + Application.PathSeparator + Application.ActiveDocument.Name + ".err" For Input As #2

          If Err.Number = 0 Then

            WITHOUT_OLE = "X"

            Close #2

          Else

            Err.Clear

          End If

          On Error GoTo 0

        Case "USE_JAR"

          USE_JAR = Param(1)

        Case "MACROSNAME"

          MACROS_NAME = Param(1)

        Case "DEBUG_MODE"

          DEBUG_MODE = Param(1)

        Case "CLOSE_FORM"

          CLOSE_FORM = Param(1)

        Case "PRINTDIALOG"

          PRINTDIALOG = Param(1)

        Case "PROTECT"

          PROTECT_WB = Param(1)

      End Select

    End If

  Loop

 

  

  If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

    Application.Visible = True

    Stop

  End If

 

  If isAutoOpen = "X" And WITHOUT_OLE = "" Then

    CloseFileData

   

    Exit Sub

  End If

 

  If (WITHOUT_OLE = "X" Or USE_JAR = "X") And FULL_NAME <> "" Then

'    Dim App As New Word.Application

    Dim App As Word.Application

   

    If Left(UCase(Application.System.OperatingSystem), 7) = "WINDOWS" Then

      Set App = New Application

    Else

      Set App = Application

    End If

   

    App.Documents.Open FULL_NAME

    Set DocTempl = App.ActiveDocument

   

    'сбросить Режим чтения в Word 2013,

    'т.к. не заполняются колонтитулы

    If DocTempl.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = True Then

      'недостаточно сбросить Режим чтения,

      'т.к. 2013 переводит в режим Черновик

      DocTempl.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView

    End If

  Else

    Set App = DocTempl.Application

  End If

 

  

  DocTempl.Activate

 

  Set Doc = App.ActiveDocument

 

  PasteAdjTblFormat = App.Options.PasteAdjustTableFormatting

  App.Options.PasteAdjustTableFormatting = False

 

  

 

 

  If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

    App.Visible = True

    App.ScreenUpdating = True

  Else

    App.ScreenUpdating = False

    App.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

  End If

 

  Cnt = 0

  i = 0

 

  Do While Not isEndOfFileData()

    i = i + 1 'f.Line

   

    Ln = ReadLineData()

   

    ReDim Preserve Ar(1 To i) As t_Ar

    Ar(i).Col = Split(Ln, Chr(9), 6, vbBinaryCompare)

  Loop

 

  CloseFileData

 

  ProgressStep = UBound(Ar, 1) / 10

  If ProgressStep > 50 Then

    ProgressStep = 50

  End If

  If ProgressStep < 1 Then

    ProgressStep = 1

  End If

 

  Err.Clear

  ErrNumber = 0

 

  Set r = Doc.Range

 

  VarError = 0

  i = 0

  Do While Not i >= UBound(Ar, 1)

    i = i + 1

   

    App.ScreenUpdating = True

    If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

      App.ScreenUpdating = True

    Else

      App.ScreenUpdating = False

    End If

   

    'If i Mod ProgressStep = 0 Then

    CurrentTime = Time * 100000 - StartTime

    If CurrentTime > 1 Then

      CurrentTime = Time * 100000

      StartTime = CurrentTime

     

      Dim ScrUpd As String

     

      If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

        ScrUpd = ", ScreenUpdating = "

        If App.ScreenUpdating Then

          ScrUpd = ScrUpd + "true"

        Else

          ScrUpd = ScrUpd + "false"

        End If

      End If

      ProgressBar i, UBound(Ar, 1), FULL_NAME + ScrUpd

    End If

       

    With Ar(i)

'      VarName = .Col(0)

'      VarNum = .Col(1)

'      FindText = .Col(2)

'      Value = .Col(5)

   

'    ErrNumber = 0

    On Error Resume Next

    If .Col(0) = "" Then

      Set r = Doc.Range

      ErrNumber = Err.Number

    Else

      If .Col(0) <> "*" Then

        'At new VarName

        Set b = Doc.Bookmarks(.Col(0))

        Set r = b.Range

        Set CurrRange = r.Duplicate

        ErrNumber = Err.Number

       

        If ErrNumber = 0 Then

          r.Copy

          'RowsCount = r.Rows.Count

          RangeStart = r.Start

          RangeEnd = r.End

          RangeSize = RangeEnd - RangeStart

          Doc.UndoClear

        End If

     

        If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

          b.Select

          r.Select

          CurrRange.Select

        End If

     

      End If

     

      If ErrNumber = 0 Then

        If .Col(1) <> "*" Then

          'At new VarNum

          If .Col(1) <> 0 Then

            r.Move 10, 1 'RowsCount

           

            If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

              r.Select

            End If

           

            If .Col(3) = "V" Then

              Err.Clear

              Set RangeTempl = Doc.Bookmarks(.Col(5)).Range

              VarError = Err.Number

            

              If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

                RangeTempl.Select

              End If

             

              If VarError = 0 Then

                NewStart = RangeTempl.Start

                NewEnd = RangeTempl.End

                RangeTempl.Copy

                r.PasteAndFormat wdListCombineWithExistingList '(wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

         

                NewSize = NewEnd - NewStart

                NewStart = r.Start

                NewEnd = NewStart + NewSize

                r.End = NewEnd

             

                If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

                  r.Select

                End If

              End If

            Else

              Set RangeTempl = CurrRange 'b.Range

              RangeTempl.Copy

              r.PasteAndFormat wdListCombineWithExistingList '(wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

             

              b.Start = CurrRange.Start

              b.End = CurrRange.End

              NewStart = r.Start

              NewEnd = NewStart + RangeSize

              r.End = NewEnd

               

              If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

                r.Select

              End If

            End If

          End If

          Doc.UndoClear

        End If

      End If

    End If

   

    If ErrNumber = 0 Then

      If .Col(2) = "" Then

        If .Col(3) = "" Or .Col(3) = "S" Then

          If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

            r.Select

          End If

          r.Text = .Col(5)

        ElseIf .Col(3) = "M" Then

          Err.Clear

          Set Dupl = r.Duplicate

               

          If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

            Dupl.Select

          End If

         

          'MacrosName = "'" + ActiveWorkbook.Name + "'" + "!" + .Col(5)

          'MACROSNAME = .Col(5)

          'App.Run MACROSNAME, Dupl

          'If Err.Number <> 0 Then

          '  App.Run MACROSNAME

          'End If

          RunUserMacros App, .Col(5), Dupl

        End If

      Else

        If .Col(3) = "S" Then

          If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

            r.Select

          End If

          Set Fd = r.Find

          Fd.Execute FindText:=.Col(2), replacewith:=.Col(5), Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        End If

      End If

    End If

    End With

    Err.Clear

  Loop

  Doc.UndoClear

 

  

  i = 0

  Do While Not i >= UBound(Ar, 1)

    i = i + 1

    With Ar(i)

      If (.Col(0) <> "" And .Col(0) <> "*" And _

          Val(.Col(1)) <> 0 And .Col(1) <> "*") Then

        Err.Clear

        Set b = Doc.Bookmarks(.Col(0))

        If Err.Number = 0 Then

          Set r = b.Range

          If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

            r.Select

          End If

          r.Delete

          Set r = b.Range

          If Err.Number = 0 Then

            If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

              r.Select

            End If

            r.Cells.Delete

          End If

        End If

      End If

      If .Col(3) = "V" Then

        Err.Clear

        Set b = Doc.Bookmarks(.Col(5))

        If Err.Number = 0 Then

          Set r = b.Range

          If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

            r.Select

          End If

          r.Delete

          Set r = b.Range

          If Err.Number = 0 Then

            If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

              r.Select

            End If

            r.Cells.Delete

          End If

        End If

      ElseIf .Col(3) = "D" Then

        Err.Clear

        Set b = Doc.Bookmarks(.Col(0))

        If Err.Number = 0 Then

          Set r = b.Range

          If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

            r.Select

          End If

          r.Delete

          Set r = b.Range

          If Err.Number = 0 Then

            If DEBUG_MODE = "X" Then

              r.Select

            End If

            r.Cells.Delete

          End If

        End If

      End If

    End With

  Loop

  Doc.UndoClear

 

  With App

    .ScreenUpdating = True

    .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll

  End With

  With Options

    .CheckSpellingAsYouType = CheckSpel

    .CheckGrammarAsYouType = CheckGram

    .PasteAdjustTableFormatting = PasteAdjTblFormat

  End With

 

  If WITHOUT_OLE = "X" Or USE_JAR = "X" Then

    If PROTECT_WB = "X" Then

      Err.Clear

      Psw = Time

      Doc.Protect Type:=3, noreset:=False, Password:=Psw

      If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        Err.Clear

        Doc.Protect Type:=1, noreset:=False, Password:=Psw

      End If

    End If

   

    Dim New_FULL_NAME As String, ErrSave, Saved_as_PDF As Boolean

    New_FULL_NAME = FILE_PATH + FILE_NAME

    If UCase(FULL_NAME) <> UCase(New_FULL_NAME) And FILE_NAME <> "" Then 'New_FULL_NAME <> ""

      MakeFullDir New_FULL_NAME

 

      If File_as_PDF(New_FULL_NAME) Then

        Doc.Save

        ErrSave = Save_as_PDF(Doc, New_FULL_NAME)

        If ErrSave = 0 Then

          Saved_as_PDF = True

        End If

      Else

        Err.Clear

        Doc.SaveAs FileName:=New_FULL_NAME

        ErrSave = Err.Number

        If ErrSave <> 0 Then

          Doc.Save

        End If

      End If

    Else

      Doc.Save

    End If

     

        

    App.DisplayAlerts = True

    App.ScreenUpdating = True

   

    If CLOSE_FORM <> "X" Then

      If Not Saved_as_PDF Then

        With App

          .DisplayAlerts = True

          .ScreenUpdating = True

          .Visible = True

        End With

      Else

        Open_as_PDF New_FULL_NAME

      End If

    End If

   

    If PRINTDIALOG = "X" Then

      If Not Saved_as_PDF Then

        ResDialogPrint = App.Dialogs.Item(wdDialogFilePrint).Show

      End If

    End If

   

    If CLOSE_FORM = "X" Or _

      PRINTDIALOG = "X" Or _

      Saved_as_PDF Then

      App.Quit

    End If

   

  End If

End Sub

 

Sub RunUserMacros(App, Val, Rng)

  Dim MACROSNAME As String, Param1 As String, it_Params, Cnt As Integer

         

  

  it_Params = Split(Val, Chr(9), 2, vbBinaryCompare)

  Cnt = UBound(it_Params)

  On Error Resume Next

  Err.Clear

   

  If Cnt >= 1 Then

    MACROSNAME = it_Params(0)

    Param1 = it_Params(1)

   

    App.Run MACROSNAME, Rng, Param1

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

      App.Run MACROSNAME, Param1

    End If

  Else

    MACROSNAME = Val

    App.Run MACROSNAME, Rng

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

      App.Run MACROSNAME

    End If

  End If

  Err.Clear

End Sub

 

Sub ProgressBar(LenPart, LenAll, Txt)

  UserFormProgress.LabelText.Caption = Txt

  UserFormProgress.LabelProgress.Width = (LenPart / LenAll) * UserFormProgress.FrameProgress.Width

'  UserFormProgress.Show

  UserFormProgress.Repaint

  DoEvents

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger?

Comment: Yes. But I can't catch the error because it appears not permanently.

Comment: What error? Could you be more specific?

Comment: There is no error. Randomly, the macro stops filling the template with data. For example, in 3 out of 10 cases, not all data will be displayed in the document. In addition, the same table can lose rows anywhere.

Comment: In debugging, I noticed that the template does not seem to have time to update and the macro jumps to the next data set. Perhaps there is some parameter to slow down the speed or wait for the insertion into the template?